# Moderator Pro Tempore

Tags: discussion, 7-essential-questions, moderation

This community needs to contribute some names they would like to act as provisional Moderators. Please read this: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

Here are some basic guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity ([see this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/elect-our-provisional-moderators) for reference).
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

Here is what we are looking for in a Moderator...

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

(*Originally written by Robert Cartaino [for the Home Improvement Stack Exchange](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/moderator-pro-tempore)*)

---

I incorrectly assumed these moderators would remain until the end of the beta, but apparently the next election will be [in *several weeks*](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) (6-8?) after the first appointment. So that would imply the highest voted nominees will be **appointed around Aug 26** (one week in the public beta), and the next election could be at the end of September or the beginning of October. **So don't be afraid to vote, if they turn out to be dictators we can chop their heads off at the next revolution!**

Comment: Do we permit self nominations?

Comment: Normally this is allowed, and it is an easy way to see who wants to be a moderator. As they say on Wikipedia: **be bold**!

Comment: How many moderators will be appointed? Is there a recommended moderator/user ratio?

Comment: Most sites have three or four moderators, only Cooking has six (too many chefs in the same kitchen?), and Home Improvement has two. It might also depend on the outcome of the vote: if the first four nominees have many votes and then a jump down for the fifth, the cut-off will probably be there.

Comment: It would be nice to know if anyone here is actively involved in the core wordpress codebase. That would certainly be a plus re: moderation, and would help to foster ties between the two communities.

Comment: Hakre was pretty active on the IRC dev-channels. I assume he still is, though I don't know.

Answer (score 7):

[MikeSchinkel http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/81df87e0d3e269d6fa6a17c6914fd656?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/81df87e0d3e269d6fa6a17c6914fd656?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG)
I nominate [**MikeSchinkel**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/89). He writes [many good answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/89), and is [also active on the Meta site](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/89/mikeschinkel). A negative point could be that [he doesn't have that much experience on the regular Stack Overflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102699/mikeschinkel). Or is this positive?

Comment: Wow, thanks @Jan! Yes, I would accept.

Comment: Mike is very active and has already shown willingness to moderate (by proxy) in a polite and helpful manner, so he sure gets my vote!

Comment: Thanks @Bobby Jack, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

[Adam Backstrom http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cc1b574406402333af845bfcefa90e98?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cc1b574406402333af845bfcefa90e98?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG)
I nominate **Adam Backstrom**. He writes [clarifying answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/66), is also [active on this meta site](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/66/adam-backstrom), and [has experience on the regular Stack Overflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7675/adam-backstrom).

**Adam says:** I accept, until I die or you find somebody better. Hopefully we will see a new crop of active users this afternoon, when the public beta starts!

Answer (score 3):

[John P Bloch http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b92487caa9c771ca1326bacaf933c13e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b92487caa9c771ca1326bacaf933c13e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG)
I nominate **[John P Bloch](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11/john-p-bloch)** - his answers are of a very high quality, and he seems very willing to engage in commentary outside the regular flow of Q&A.

- [WordPress Answers profile](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/11/john-p-bloch)

Comment: He is also [very active on the regular Stack Overflow site](http://stackoverflow.com/users/337269/john-p-bloch).

Comment: *@Jan Fabry* - Part of me thinks being a regular on StackOverflow is not necessarily a good thing for WordPress Answers (although my comment has nothing otherwise to do with the nomination of *@John P Bloch* who I would support.)

Comment: John is the second highest in rep on the parent site.

Answer (score 3):

[EAMann http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/46093583d8895095adb1b0071c505af2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/46093583d8895095adb1b0071c505af2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG)

I'd also like to nominate myself - [Meta Profile](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46/eamann) - [WordPress Answers Profile](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/46/eamann) - [Stack Overflow Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326224/eamann).  I try to be active where I can :-)

Comment: I second @EAMann's nomination.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Jan Fabry]
I nominate [**Jan Fabry**](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8/jan-fabry). He has been reasonably active on the main site but very active on meta and has good experience with StackOverflow this could be out best link there SO/SE.

---

Thanks for the nomination, I accept it. I don't know whether I would be the best link to SO/SE, but I am very interested in the meta stuff, community building, and indeed moderation. The Q&A on the main site seems to be of very high quality, so I didn't feel the need to give that much answers myself. I hope you won't hold that against me, but I would be no less motivated to participate if I'm not elected as a moderator.

I seem to be the first non-USA nominee, but I think we need more, to cover the times when the other mods should be asleep. So if you are from another part of the globe, please stand up!

Comment: The more answers Jan is doing, the more I like to read them. I really appreciate his SE knowlege, this often adds the needed impulse / point of view on stuff that would be otherwise missing.

Answer (score 3):

[tnorthcutt http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dab4673605e74a9d031e16c2dd8dcb28?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dab4673605e74a9d031e16c2dd8dcb28?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG)
I nominate [**tnorthcutt**](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/49/tnorthcutt) (assuming he uploads an headshot. :)  He's been active on both meta and the main site both asking and answering questions and I think he's got the right temperament to be a moderator.

(Edit: Headshot uploaded!  And thanks! -tn)

Comment: I'd be honored to help out.  Web community development/growth is something I'm very interested in (and working on professionally), and I'd love the opportunity to help this site grow and succeed.