# When will our pro tem moderators be put in place?

Tags: discussion

A thread was started to [nominate temporary moderators](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45/moderator-pro-tempore). It received a (fairly small) bit of attention, but now that we've nominated and voted (however little) on them, how are they given moderator powers?  There's enough volume now that I think it is necessary to have a few to help keep things as orderly and true to the intentions of this site as possible, especially now in the early stages of the community, when the collective personality of the site is still forming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On other sites this was done when the site was [in public beta for one week](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), so the new people also get to say something. [Some of the first users are from the Stack Overflow team](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=oldest), and of course they have moderation powers, so if you flag a post, I think they can intervene (but probably not for the smaller, but also important, [housekeeping tasks](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68/what-should-our-question-title-guidelines-be/69#69)).